# Passing file Blob as a prop to a react component causes `TypeError: Illegal invocation` on Blob.slice()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

I have a simple file chunking system to upload data to a server via many chunks, to do this I delegate the splitting and uploading task to a dedicated component... However when passing the received Blob, from user, to my dedicated component, the prop in that component doesn't seem to contain anything... Indeed [Blob.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice) throws `TypeError: Illegal invocation`

```js
const Uploader = ({ fileBlob }) => {
     useEffect(() => {
          let chunk = fileBlob.slice(0, fileBlob.size() / 2); // Throws
     });

     return (<some stuff />)
}

const BlobFromUser = () => {
    const fileUpload = (fileBlob) => {
         //let chunk = fileBlob.slice(0, fileBlob.size / 2); Tried here and it works
         notify(<Uploader fileBlob={fileBlob} />);
    }

    return (<file upload user form triggers fileUpload()/>)
}
```

Comment: `Blob.prototype.size` isn't supposed to be a function, so this should throw a `TypeError: fileBlob.size is not a function`. That it doesn't means that `fileBlob` is not a Blob. And whatever this `fileBlob` is, it apparently badly referenced a real Blob's `.slice()` method without properly binding it to the instance. So log `fileBlob`, search what kind of weirdness it is and dig down who made it. Then if it really has a value fix it, otherwise just get rid of it and use the real Blob object.

Comment: My bad for the `size()`, it's just a typo in this post... This is the standard Web API Blob interface btw, however this strange behavior only happens when passing blob to a react component, passing it to a standard js function function doesn't cause any issue

Comment: What does `notify` do? How (and with what argument) is `fileUpload` called exactly? Please make a [mcve].